# Determine a unit-speed parametrisation for the curves

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I am stuck at a problem that seems quite easy, but I just couldn't sort it out.

Determine a unit-speed parametrisation for the curves:

(i) $\gamma(t) = $(cos$^2(t)$, sin$^2(t))$ for $t∈(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$

(ii) $\gamma(t) = (t$, cosh$t)$ for $t∈R$

---

I know that these two curves are regular since $||\gamma \dot (t)||$ never vanishes within their domain, and we need it to be $1$ to make it unit-speed.

In (i), I found $\gamma \dot (t) = (-2$ sin$t$ cos$t$, $2$ sin$t$ cos$t)$, and $||\gamma \dot (t)|| =2 \sqrt(2)$ sin$t$ cos$t = \sqrt(2)$sin$2t$. Then $\Gamma \dot(t) = \frac{\gamma \dot (t)}{||\gamma \dot (t)||} = (-\frac{\sqrt(2)}{2}, \frac{\sqrt(2)}{2})$, which makes $\Gamma(t) = (-\frac{\sqrt(2)}{2}t, \frac{\sqrt(2)}{2}t)$.

$\Gamma(t)$ satisfies the conditions of unit speed, but the method and result do seem weird. This couldn't be applied to (ii), either, due to the difficulties in integrating the division result.

Could someone please guide me to the right track? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is not correct. Note that $\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t = 1$, so the curve is (part of) the line $x+y=1$. When you integrated to obtain $\Gamma(t)$, you forgot the integration constants. That's why you obtained a line that is parallel to the correct line.

This method will not work in general. In the simple case of a line it works, but here's the general approach:

*Step 1.* Find the arclength parameter:
$$ 
 s(t) = \int_0^t \|\dot\gamma(t)\|\,dt = \int_0^t \sqrt{2}\sin 2t\,dt 
     = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left(1-\cos 2t\right).
$$
*Step 2.* Write the parameter $t=t(s)$ in function of the arclength $s$. This means you have to find the inverse of the function $s(t)$:
$$ t=\frac{1}{2}\arccos(1-\sqrt{2}s).$$
*Step 3.* Substitute this expression in the parametrisation $\gamma(t)$. You will obtain
$$ 
 \gamma(s) = \left(1-\frac{s}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{s}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \quad s\in(0,\sqrt{2}).
$$
Now you can tackle the curve in (ii).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is (ii) $\gamma(s) = (arcosh(s),s)$? How can I deal with the updated domain of $s$? Since $cosh(t)$ would have inverse only within part of $R$ (where $cosh(t)$ is bijective) but the given curve is defined in the whole $R$..

Comment: I think there's a mistake. I find $s(t)=\sinh t+c$, where $c$ is a constant that depends on the starting point on the curve your choose.) So $t=\mathrm{arcsinh}(s-c)$, and this is defined on whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: ahhhhh you are right! I put cosh$t$ as the integral of cosh$t$ which was super ridiculous. Thanks heaps!